# I can't update my SQL row

Tags: php, sql

I try to update data in my row, but I can't, hmm I get message, that everything went good, but row doesn't change at all. I think I do something wrong with incrementing, I mean that data in row is a string, that's why ++  may not work on it. I use echo to see what data is in for example $ip, $lower etc, to see on what data script is going to work, and everything goes good, but UPDATE doesn't. This is my code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip_for_map;
$ip_data_for_map = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));
$country_upper = $ip_data_for_map->geoplugin_countryCode;
echo $country_upper;
$country_lower = strtolower($country_upper);
echo $country_lower;
$main_for_table = 1;
$take_from_sql_country = "SELECT $country_lower FROM table WHERE main='$main_for_table'";
$country_taken_from_table = mysqli_query($dbc, $take_from_sql_country);
$row_sl_map = mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_taken_from_table);
$row_country_data = $row_sl_map['$country_lower']; 
$row_final = $row_country_data++;
$update_countrys_row = "UPDATE table SET $country_lower='$row_final' WHERE main='$main_for_table'";
$update_country_final = mysqli_query($dbc, $update_countrys_row);
if(!$update_country_final)
{
    echo 'BADSHIT';
}
else
{
    echo 'BRAVO';
}
```

Comment: what value you get for $country_lower ?

Comment: Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix all your sql injection, and your code remains **very vunerable** towards SQL injection. If `geoplugin.net` changed their output, they could destroy your entire database. Use prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: @user3184915 The "lazy" way is to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on ANY variable before you inject it into the query.

Comment: @h2ooooooo totally forgot... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$row_country_data = $row_sl_map['$country_lower'];
```

This line is literally looking for an array key called `$country_lower`, not the key contained in the variable `$country_lower`.

Remove the single quotes.

It should also be noted that, even if the query results in no update (as is the case in your erroneous code), the query itself still succeeds.

Comment: okay I did what you said, but I still have "0" in this row. It doesn't increment

Comment: Try `+1` instead of `++`.